# How to send form data to ActionSupport using Ajax and Struts2

Tags: java, ajax, json, hibernate, struts2

when am not using Ajax then all well and good with same code. but using ajax here am got null vale for same public String execute() throws Exception { String strAction = cartItemForm.getAction(); /*i am geting null here using ajax call but simple stuts2 getting action value which i have in `<s:hidden name="action" value="Add" id="action" />` it means getting add */ return "success"; }

this is jsp

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function submitAjax()  
  {  
   JSONobj = {cartItem:{
     description : $("description").val(),
     price :$("price").val(),
     action : $("action").val(),
     quantity :$("quantity").val(),
   } };
   JSONstr = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);

   jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'Cart.action', 
        data:JSONstr,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(){window.alert("done");}
    });
}  

</script>
<s:form>
  <s:hidden name="modelNo"     value="%{#attr.productId}"                    />  
  <s:hidden name="description" value="%{#attr.productName}" id="description" />
  <s:hidden name="price"       value="%{#attr.listprice}"   id="price"       />
  <s:hidden name="action"      value="Add"                  id="action"      />

  <s:submit value="add to cart" cssClass="submit_button" theme="simple"      />
</s:form>
```

This is struts.xml

```
 <action name="Cart" class="struts.cart.action.CartAction">
    <result type="json"/> 
 </action>
```

Here is MY Action Class

```
  public class CartAction extends ActionSupport 
                        implements ModelDriven, Preparable, ServletRequestAware {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3670063011948002290L;
public  static final String ADD = "Add";
public  static final String DELETE = "Delete";
public  static final String UPDATE = "Update";  
public  static final String CART_SESSION = "Cart";

    private HttpServletRequest  request;
    private CartItemForm        cartItemForm;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String strAction = cartItemForm.getAction();//i am geting null here
        return "success";
    }

    public Object getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Cart getModel "+cartItemForm);
        return cartItemForm;
    }

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Cart prepare "+cartItemForm);
        cartItemForm=new CartItemForm();
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest  httpServletRequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request = httpServletRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider fixing your method templates, or at the very least, deleting the useless comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if i have understand your question, it is very straightforward to do this. Here is a possible solution with jquery:

```
<s:form id="myForm">
  <s:hidden name="modelNo" value="%{#attr.productId}"></s:hidden>  
  <s:hidden id="description" name="description" value="%{#attr.productName}"></s:hidden>
  <s:hidden id="price" name="price" value="%{#attr.listprice}"></s:hidden>
  <s:hidden id="action" name="action" value="Add"></s:hidden>
  <s:submit id="#submit" value="add to cart" cssClass="submit_button" theme="simple"></s:submit>
</s:form>

<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var formData = $("#myForm").serialize(); //get all data from form
          //do the POST thingies
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url_to_your_struts2_action",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });

        return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: i am still geting null value pls any one chek it and crrect me

Comment: how to get formData value in ActionSuport Class. @aiwo99

Comment: @user2098768 if you have `param` interceptor, you can easily define variables in your action class with the name of parameter and getter, setters

Comment: can any one have answer for this ? even I am facing the same issue. I have declared member variables in action class and same name of variables are being used in form fields . So when an action class method is called on submit ( without using ajax ) the action class member variables will be getting the values. but when we call action from ajax those members are getting null values. Tried sending form by serializing it, its not working..